# Subsetting a data frame using another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm having trouble with something that shouldn't be that hard to come around. What I would like to do is subsetting a `data.frame` by using another `data.frame`, and more precisely, by using a certain parameter. 
Here goes the example:

```
df1<- t(data.frame(A=c("ABI", "BET", "ALN", "SPH", "PTI", "DIC", "PTD"), B=c("0.5","3","0","0","5","0","15"), C=c("0","0","3","15","15","0","0"), D=c("0.5","0.5","0.5","0","0","0","0"), E=c("37.5","37.5","0.5","62.5","0.5","0.5","1")))
df2<- data.frame(A=c("ABI", "BET", "ALN", "SPH", "PTI", "DIC", "PTD"), B=c("vasc", "vasc","vasc","spha", "moss","moss","moss"), C=c("a", "a", "b", "a", "c","d","a"))
```

Now, let's say that I want in my `df1` only the objects A (here they are species) that are "vasc" in df2 in my df1. 
For that I've tried a few things such as:

```
df3 <- subset(df2, B=="vasc")
df4 <- df1[,c(df1, as.vector(df2))]
```

But in doing so, I have an error of type:

> Error in df1[, c(df1, as.vector(df2))] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Therefore, I've tried to unlist my dataframes but nothing seems to work. I've been on this problem for a while now and I did explore the forum to see if anyone had an elegant solution to my problem but it looks like not. 
Another way of doing this subsetting was to do the following bit of code, but it didn't work either even though I felt closer to the solution:

```
 try11 <- list(df2, df1)%>% rbindlist(., fill=T)  # with df1 not transposed
 df11 <- try11[try11=="vasc",]
```

I hope the code is good enough and my explanation clear enough.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

dtPruned <- df1[A %in% df2[B == "vasc", A]]
```

Make sure to remove the t() call in your df1 definition for this to work, however. Basically, what it's doing is selecting the A column in df2 where B = "vasc". It then selects the rows from df1 where A is in those A's from df2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
species <- as.character(df2[df2$B == "vasc",1])

df1 %>% 
    slice(A %in% species)

## A tibble: 3 x 5
#  A     B     C     D     E
#  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
#1 ABI   0.5   0     0.5   37.5
#2 ABI   0.5   0     0.5   37.5
#3 ABI   0.5   0     0.5   37.5
```

---

#### PS

Your data contains only `factor`. Maybe you want yo use number as `numeric` class.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. First we create a character vector (`x`) of all `A` values where `B == vasc` in `df2`. Then we select columns from `df1` where `A == x`:

```
# Create a character vector of all A values when B == vasc
x <- as.character(df2[df2$B == "vasc", 1])

# Select columns where row A == x
df1[, which(df1[1, ] %in% x)]
```

> ```
>   [,1]   [,2]   [,3] 
> A "ABI"  "BET"  "ALN"
> B "0.5"  "3"    "0"  
> C "0"    "0"    "3"  
> D "0.5"  "0.5"  "0.5"
> E "37.5" "37.5" "0.5"
> ```

If we avoid the `t` call, we can do:

```
df1[df1$A %in% df2[df2$B == "vasc", 1], ]
```

> ```
>     A   B C   D    E
> 1 ABI 0.5 0 0.5 37.5
> 2 BET   3 0 0.5 37.5
> 3 ALN   0 3 0.5  0.5
> ```

We could transpose the data frame to retain the same format as above:

```
t(df1[df1$A %in% df2[df2$B == "vasc", 1], ])
```

> ```
>   1      2      3    
> A "ABI"  "BET"  "ALN"
> B "0.5"  "3"    "0"  
> C "0"    "0"    "3"  
> D "0.5"  "0.5"  "0.5"
> E "37.5" "37.5" "0.5"
> ```

---

Data:

```
df1 <- t(data.frame(
  A = c("ABI", "BET", "ALN", "SPH", "PTI", "DIC", "PTD"), 
  B = c("0.5","3","0","0","5","0","15"), 
  C = c("0","0","3","15","15","0","0"), 
  D = c("0.5","0.5","0.5","0","0","0","0"), 
  E = c("37.5","37.5","0.5","62.5","0.5","0.5","1")
  )
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  A = c("ABI", "BET", "ALN", "SPH", "PTI", "DIC", "PTD"), 
  B = c("vasc", "vasc","vasc","spha", "moss","moss","moss"), 
  C = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "c","d","a")
)
```